# Ruby on Rails: Active Admin and Heroku - dashboard error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, activeadmin

I have some Ruby on Rails applications that are using Active Admin gem. Rails version is 3.2.6, Active Admin version is 0.4.4.

I am pushing these applications to Heroku, then doing migrations and everything is working fine. But after some time (when application restarts) i'm starting to get 404 error when trying to open admin page (like *myapp/admin*). In logs there is an error:

**ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Admin::DashboardController)**

Moreover, if i'm trying to open some other admin page (like *myapp/admin/videos* - to administer videos) everything is still working fine, but error 404 persists when opening Dashboard page.

I have tried to put

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.assets.compile = true
```

to my config files, but all the same.

Basically the scheme is as follows:

1. I make some changes to the app, commit the changes with "git add .", "git commit" and push it to Heroku
2. I open the /admin page on Heroku and it works fine
3. After application restarts i get 404 error when visiting /admin, but everything still works when accessing other admin pages, not dashboard
4. GoTo 1

I'm still unsure if the error appears when the app is restarted by itself (not by "heroku restart").

Any ideas why this is happening? Maybe someone can advice how to switch off this Dashboard and use my *myapp/admin/videos* as the default admin page?

Answer (score 0):

I had this very same problem, and since it complaints about the ActiveAdmin Dashboard, and it is now deprecated I proceeded to update my dashboard.rb file to [the new Dashboard style](https://raw.github.com/gregbell/active_admin/master/lib/generators/active_admin/install/templates/dashboard.rb) and that solved the problem.

(I got that file from [here](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/1493#issuecomment-6976307)).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue.
Check whether you have to upgrade ActiveAdmin to new version 
When upgrading to a new version of ActiveAdmin you may need to run

```
rails generate active_admin:assets
```

If you get:

```
uninitialized constant Admin::DashboardController
```

Use the New default page for admin/dashboard.rb

which is like following,

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Dashboard" do

  menu :priority => 1, :label => proc{ I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard") }

  content :title => proc{ I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard") } do
    div :class => "blank_slate_container", :id => "dashboard_default_message" do
      span :class => "blank_slate" do
        span I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard_welcome.welcome")
        small I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard_welcome.call_to_action")
      end
    end

    # Here is an example of a simple dashboard with columns and panels.
    #
    # columns do
    #   column do
    #     panel "Recent Posts" do
    #       ul do
    #         Post.recent(5).map do |post|
    #           li link_to(post.title, admin_post_path(post))
    #         end
    #       end
    #     end
    #   end

    #   column do
    #     panel "Info" do
    #       para "Welcome to ActiveAdmin."
    #     end
    #   end
    # end
  end # content
end
```